# Angular2 route paths not working when URL is empty

Tags: angular2-routing

Following is how my `app`'s 'tree' looks like:

[image]

I want my app to go to the 'home' route by default (when the path is empty). (`localhost:3000/home`). 
But it always goes to `localhost:3000/list`.

**app-routing.module.ts**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'userManagement', loadChildren: 'app/userManagement/user-    management.module#UserManagementModule' }]
```

**user-management.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'list', component: UserListComponent }]
```

However, when the redirections works fine when triggered through HTML links:

**app-component.html**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a> <!--localhost:3000/home-->
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="userManagement" routerLinkActive="active">Link</a> <!--localhost:3000/userManagement/list-->
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to separate your routes as you separate your modules.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {UserManagementRoutes} from "./userManagement/userManagement.routes";
import {HomeRoutes} from "./home/home.routes";

export const routes: Routes = [
    ...UserManagementRoutes,
    ...HomeRoutes,
    { path: '',  redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];


import {Route} from '@angular/router';
import {UserManagementComponent} from "./userManagement.component";

export const UserManagementRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'userManagement',
    children: [
      {path: '',component: UserManagementComponent}
    ]
  }
];



import {Route} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";

export const UserManagementRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    children: [
      {path: '',component: HomeComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```